# How does the kernel keep track of frames being mapped to other processes?

Tags: linux-kernel, shared-memory, virtual-memory

In regards to [minor page faults](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault#Minor), Wikipedia says:

> The page fault handler in the operating system merely needs to make the entry for that page in the memory management unit point to the page in memory and indicate that the page is loaded in memory; it does not need to read the page into memory. **This could happen if the memory is shared by different programs and the page is already brought into memory for other programs.**

How does the kernel know that a page has already been brought into memory by another process? From my understanding, for any given executing process, the kernel is only concerned with that process's page table, so if there's some frame that's already mapped by another process, how is the kernel determining this?

It would be awesome too if you could also point out the relevant code that does this, as I was scanning around [here](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.28/mm/memory.c#L2317) (linked from [this](https://manybutfinite.com/post/how-the-kernel-manages-your-memory/) article) and couldn't find the relevant part of the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a virtual memory system the operating system has to maintain a representation of a process's address space in secondary storage. That is the "virtual" part of virtual memory.

The virtual representation is usually divided into sections. Each section contains pages with the same attributes (r/w/rw/rx) and is stored contiguously.

Usually, if a processes share memory, they share entire sections.

Somewhere the operating system has to store a header describing the section. That header will indicate if and where the section is loaded in physical memory. Each process has to have a data structure that indicates where the section is mapped to the logical address space.

Keep in mind that this mechanism can be used for pageable areas of the operating system that are shared by all processes.

When a page fault occurs, the page fault handler has to identify what section contains the page that caused the fault. Then it can identify from the section's header if it resides in physical memory.

The article you mention refers to the VMS operating system where this kind of soft fault is more likely to occur. In VMS libraries are installed by the operating system so that all processes are forced to share the same code.

Comment: Thank you for the response! So when you say "Then it can identify from the section's header if it resides in physical memory" -is this section header shared amongst all processes, meaning that the OS doesn't have to go through each process to see if it maps the section? In addition does the section header contain which processes currently map that section?

Comment: It would have to be shared by all processes.